# Java applet hangs randomly on Mac

Tags: java, macos, applet, java-web-start

I have some annoying issue with Mac OS X.
Some feature in system which i developing uses Java Aplet, Java Web Start
Everything works perfectly except Mac OS.
The applet starts ok, java consol is showing. When i try to use it - choose some catalog from JFileChooser it sometimes works, sometimes stuck.

Before it stuck i can clik the "browse" button but JFileChooser never occur and Java Console is not responding, i cant even scroll.

It works randomly, means sometimes i can choose directory few times and everything is ok but other time it stops after first catalog.

Someone force with same or similar issue ?

PS the java version is 1.8.0_161, and it's Mac OS X 10.11 EL Capitan

Comment: Are you using a JFileChooser in an applet ? If yes, this applet must be signed and granted a local file access.

Comment: ok here comes the jeremiad about Applets...

Comment: Yes, applet using JFileChooser. I'm not sure that the problem related to permissions because when file explorer occures i am able to browse catalogs and choose them. Maybe i'm wrong, i will check, thanks :)

Comment: Tip: Add @olikaf (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. On a wider note, I'm surprised that an applet launches at all, let alone on multiple systems. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). BTW - what does this applet do? (e.g. file uploader?)